# FB.AppRequest 0 objects are given message

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to send a invitation with FB.AppRequest and i'm getting this error message:

> This action type requires 1 1 object but 0 0 objects are given.

my request is made as follows.

`FB.AppRequest("Come play this great game!", InvitePlayersIds);`

This InvitePlayerIds is a collection with the player ids i've got through

`FB.API("/me/invitable_friends", HttpMethod.GET, InvitableFriendsCallback);`

Someone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Forget, the problem was another thing...

I was compiling to a different folder than the configured on facebook, so, after i changed to the right folder the code above works fine.

rookie mistake....